# geb using grapes - download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar

Tags: groovy, geb

I'm trying to run geb using the grab examples in the [user guide](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#installation__usage) for pulling in dependencies:

```
$ cat my.groovy
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:0.9.2"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.26.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.26.0")
])
import geb.Browser

Browser.drive{
    go "http://grails.org/plugins/"

}
```

However, the above code results in:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I converted the project into a gradle project, removing the Grapes and Grab annotations, and the dependencies are OK. I am still interested in getting the annotated version working though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trying to get an old version of that Codec... just force a newer one by adding an explicit annotation.  I also updated the selenium dependency versions to run against my latest n greatest FireFox, v 29.0 at the time of this writing:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:0.9.2"),
    @Grab(group='commons-codec', module='commons-codec', version='1.9'),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.41.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.41.0")
])
```

And of course make sure you have FireFox installed on your machine.